# Uncaught TypeError: app.Med.aff is not a function

Tags: typescript

I created Code typescript when I add JQuery and I use requirejs and amd module for compilation, But when I lunched in browser I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: app.Med.aff is not a function

Code app.ts:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"


    export class Med{
        public aff(){
            $('#med').click(function(eventObject){
                $('#test').show();
            })
        }
    }
```

code config.ts:

```
require(
        ['app'],
        function(app: any){
            app.Med.aff()
        }, 

        function (err: any) { 
            console.error('ERROR: ', err.requireType); 
            console.error('MODULES: ', err.requireModules); 
        } 
    );
```

code app.js:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery"], function (require, exports, $) {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
        var Med = (function () {
            function Med() {
            }
            Med.prototype.aff = function () {
                $('#med').click(function (eventObject) {
                    $('#test').show();
                });
            };
            return Med;
        }());
        exports.Med = Med;
    });
```

code config.js:

```
"use strict";
    require(['app'], function (app) {
        app.Med.aff();
    }, function (err) {
        console.error('ERROR: ', err.requireType);
        console.error('MODULES: ', err.requireModules);
    });
```

and Code tsconfig.json:

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "amd",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "lib": ["es2016","dom"],                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
        "strict": true                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      },

      "exclude": [
        "./build",
        "./node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`aff` is defined as prototype method.

You need to either create an instance of `Med` and call it `new Med().aff()`

Or declare `aff` as static

```
export class Med{
    static aff(){
        $('#med').click(function(eventObject){
            $('#test').show();
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: when  created static aff() .. bug resolved but how to creat new Med().aff() !!! and app in config.ts !

Comment: @devit2017 I don't know what your requirements are. You could do it like `app.medInstance = new Med` and then use it like `app.medInstace.aff()`. But why do you want `Med` to be a class if you are planning to use only one instance of it?

Comment: @devit2017 What does it suppose to mean "is not resolved". Any errors?

Comment: I create in code app.medInstance = new Med then app.medInstace.aff() and in app.ts I create public aff() { ... } but I have also error : Uncaught TypeError: app.Med.aff is not a function

Comment: @devit2017 "Uncaught TypeError: app.Med.aff is not a function " it means you are still calling `app.Med.aff()` instead of `app.medInstance.aff()`. BTW you need to export `exports.medInstance = new Med` not `app.medInstance = ...` as I wrote before.

Answer (score 0):

@Yury

this code work :

Code app.ts:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"


    export class Med{
        public aff(){
            $('#med').click(function(eventObject){
                $('#test').toggle('slow');
            })
        }
    }

    let f = new Med()
    f.aff();
```

code config.ts:

```
require(
['app'],
function(app: any){

}, 

function (err: any) { 
    console.error('ERROR: ', err.requireType); 
    console.error('MODULES: ', err.requireModules); 
}
```

);

thank you my friend